# How to resolve the syntax error around FROM in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made the following query:

```
    SELECT cust_number, cust_name, COUNT(ord_number) AS number_of_orders,
    FROM MSC_Customer, MSC_Order
    WHERE MSC_Customer.cust_number = MSC_Order.cust_number
    GROUP BY cust_number
```

This produces the following error:

```
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

    Completion time: 2021-10-20T19:34:43.8096950-04:00
```

I don't know how to fix this error.

[Original post below]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pck7.png)

A select statement that displays customer number, customer name, and the number of orders that belonged to the customer. Two tables need to be joined.

Comment: Please don't post tiny screenshots. Please copy paste your SQL code and your error message into the question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) SQL and error messages are both text, and can be copied/pasted directly into your post. Please [edit] your post to remove the image and provide the appropriate text.

Comment: You have an extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the comma just before FROM.